# Acumulador/Contador usando bucle for en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

¿conocéis el cuento de Jack y las judias mágicas?. Seguro que si. Bueno. Tengo que hacer un programa que pida el numero de horas que han pasado y dar la longitud de la judia mágica. En los comentarios del programa que hice están todos los datos...

Yo hice esto:

```
'''Jack y las judias mágicas....

Cada hora crece 150% y gana un extra de 30cm
Primera hora ============ 100cms
2 hora  100 x 1.5 + 30 =    180
3 hora  180 x 1.5 + 30 =    300
4 hora 300 x 1.5 + 30 =     480...etc
El programa debe pedir el numero de horas que han pasado y mostrar el crecimiento'''

print("Jack y las judias mágicas")
altura = 100
horas = (input("Introduce en el número de horas que han pasado: "))

print("Despues de una hora el tallo medía", altura, "cms")
for i in horas:
    altura = altura*1.5+30
    print("Despues de ", horas , " horas, la judia mágica mide ", altura, "cms") 
    print("O en metros la altura de ", altura/100)
print("Y todavia creciendo...")'''
```

No doy con la solucion, siempre me da la misma cantidad, asi que intento multiplicar en el cuerpo de "for" las horas, pero me dice que no es posible. Si las horas las pongo como float o int, me dice que no es iterable. He probado todo lo que se me ocurrió pero sin éxito.

Asi que mirando documentacion di con el concepto de acumuladores, que segun entiendo serían algo así:

Ejemplo de Acumulador

```
x=int(input("Intro un numero: "))
sum=0
for i in range(1,x):
    sum=sum+1
    print(sum)'''
```

Intento aplicarlo a mi codigo (acumular una hora a otra) pero nunca es correcta la solucion...
Podiais, por favor, orientarme un poco, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, `input` te devuelve una cadena y lo que tú necesitas es un entero. Por lo tanto, la forma correcta es:

```
horas = int(input("Introduce en el número de horas que han pasado: "))
```

Tal como está, el `for` recorre sobre los caracteres que ingresaste, no sobre el valor. Entonces, si ingresas 2, el `for` itera sólo una vez y la variable `i` contiene el caracter '2', no el valor decimal 2.

```
print("Jack y las judias mágicas")
altura = 100
horas = int(input("Introduce en el número de horas que han pasado: "))

for i in range(horas):
    altura = altura*1.5+30
    print("Despues de ", i + 1 , " horas, la judia mágica mide ", altura, "cms")
print("Y todavia creciendo...")
```

produce:

```
Jack y las judias mágicas
Introduce en el número de horas que han pasado: 2
Despues de  1  horas, la judia mágica mide  180.0 cms
Despues de  2  horas, la judia mágica mide  300.0 cms
Y todavia creciendo...
```

Comment: Gracias @CandidMoe, me has aclarado mi error con 'int', que ahora entiendo perfectamente. Pero el resultado de la solución propuesta no es correcto. Si cada hora crece 150% y gana además un extra de 30cm...y en la primera ya tiene 100cms....**Pienso** que sería así:
Primera hora                          100cms
2 hora 100 x 1.5 + 30 = 180
3 hora 180 x 1.5 + 30 = 300
4 hora  300 x 1.5 + 30 =      480...en cambio con esa solución propuesta, en la segunda hora ya tiene el valor de la tercera. **Va adelantado una hora**. No?

Comment: Ya está @Candidmoe, el for de la función dle post mas arriba me da la solución. Es este **for i in range (1,horas):** Gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda. Solucionado.

Answer (score 0):

Si por ejemplo introduces `x=5`, tu acumulador suma desde 1 hasta 4, ya que la función range coge número hasta n-1. Imagino, que lo que quieres es que tu acumulador sume de 1 a 5. Por tanto tendrías que cambiar `range(1, x+1)` de esta manera cogerá todos tus números hasta el 5. Espero que te sea de ayuda!

Aquí te dejo una pequeña función que devuelve la altura según las horas introducidas.

```
def judias(horas):
    altura = 100
    for i in range(1, horas):
        altura = altura*1.5+30
    return altura
```

Comment: No calcula bien. Debe decir `for i in range(horas)`.

Comment: Si @CandidMoe, **está bien**, lo he comprobado. Es que ten encuenta que parte ya de 100cms, si miras el encabezamiento de mi programa lo explico, pero tambien te lo he dejado en el comentario de tu post. Muchas gracias a los dos.